# Most efficient way to check if limited 2D array can form diagonal line

Tags: algorithm, performance, multidimensional-array

Let's say i have such data structure

```
    int arr[3][3] = {
        {1, 1},
        {1, 2},
        {0, 2}
    };
```

where first number inside inner array corresponds to min and second number corresponds to max.
It would look something like this.

[image: like this.]

What is the most efficient way to check if after some columns adjusting it can form diagonal line like so.

[image: like so]

Comment: Hey Seb_, what have you tried? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I sorted the array ascending based on max value and did some nested loop trickery, it works but I wonder if this array can somehow by sorted from this state https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIA5S.png to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dscCr.png in one go and then simply check in linear loop whether column index is between min and max but I cant really figure out the sorting condition for this type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the final solution you have match each row of your array to a column which `indes[i][i]` exists in the row.
It's a matching algorithm you can find [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/hungarian-matching/)
Create your bipartite graph as rows in part `A` and indexes of final diagonal in part `B`. create edges between `row i` and `diagonal j` when `A[i][0]<=j and A[i][1]>=j` and then run the hungarian-matching on it.